# jQuery: Error With POST After Being Offline (iOS & Chrome)

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, html, google-chrome

I've built an HTML5 web application with offline capabilities (using AppCache). The program flow is:

- **Online**: *While on the network*, the app pre-loads some base information ("working").
- **Offline**: The user takes the tablet with the app *offline*, then performs their workflow on the app (e.g. inspections and grading).
- **Online**: Once the tablet *reconnects to the network*, it syncs (or uploads) the user's input into the central system/database.

We have made a business decision to use Chrome for ALL offline/HTML5 applications (because of HTML5 support).  On a Windows device (using Chrome), the sync/upload works with no problems.  If the user is using an iPad (iOS 7, Chrome), the first time they try to sync, an error is thrown - however the very first record IS actually synced.  The error that is thrown by the XHResponse object is just "error".

We are using WebAPI 2.2 on the server side, and jQuery 2.1.1 AJAX on the client side.

The client-side **JavaScript** that performs the POST is as follows:

```
try {
    var inspections = GetCompleteInspections();
    if (inspections) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inspections.length; i++) {
            var response = null;
            var data = JSON.stringify(inspections[i]);
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "api/",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (dta, textStatus, xhr) {
                    window.console.log("data:" + dta + "--");
                    if (d && d < 0) {
                        alert("dta is invalid:" + dta + "--");
                        response = "Error Uploading, please try again";
                    } else {
                        $("#inspection_" + i).hide();
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus == "timeout") {
                        alert("timeout!");
                        response = "timeout";
                    } else {
                        window.console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        var errorMessage = errorThrown || xhr.statusText;
                        response = errorMessage;
                    }
                }
            });
            if (response) {
                throw response;
            }
        }
    }
    $('#new_records').append("<tr><td>Sync Complete</td></tr>");
    $('#syncButton').hide();
    ClearInspections();
    $("#dialog-sync").dialog("close");
} catch (err) {
    $("#dialog-sync").dialog("close");
    window.alert("An error occurred during upload\n" + err);
}
```

This only appears to happen on iOS devices running Chrome. Windows devices do not have this issue. Is there any way to trace or diagnose what is going on? Or even how to prevent the error from happening?

Comment: Safari does not handle the HTML5 offline capabilities so the application wont even run.

Comment: @djm61 First of all, why is `async` set to `false`? Second, what is `try{…}`?

Comment: @djm61 Have you tried using the `$.post()` shorthand?

Comment: @017Bluefield - `async` is set to false because there are something that have to happen AFTER the post is completely (I didn't show the code here as it's not relevant to my question).  And no, I haven't tried the `$.post` shorthand.  This appears to be an iOS issue and I have logged a bug on the Apple Developer forums.  And thanks for formatting my post, much easier to read!

Comment: @djm61 Well, it doesn't seem like anyone can figure out the problem without the actual code for `GetCompleteInspections()` and `ClearInspections()`. Even if the code is irrelevant, it may still required for the script to run without errors. (No problem; glad I could help! `:)`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem once which I hacked around in a truly gross way:

Before doing the sync, I loaded a visible 1x1 transparent png from the network (set the source with a random query string to avoid caching).  Then when that image loaded (onload event) I started the JavaScript calls.

To this day I don't know if there's some underlying network issue or if this only solved it by introducing a time delay on startup, but the problem never recurred and hasn't come up in the wild.  Come to think of it, it's probably time to refactor that code...

Comment: Tried this, and for still received the same error.  Either I'm attempting to implement your "gross" solution incorrectly, or this is a bug in iOS.  I now have an iOS 8 iPad I'm playing with to see if I can still replicate the issue or not.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This error on iOS (iPhone) should be fixed by setting **async** attribute of request to **true** or completely removing this attribute