# iOS Chrome : Error:TimeoutError:DOM Exception 23

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, backbone.js

```
var thisModel = this;

    thisModel.count++; 

    var data = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
    data.append('createdOn', new Date().getTime());
    data.append('loc', viewObj.googleLocation.lon);
    data.append('loc', viewObj.googleLocation.lat);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : app.API_URL + "/add",
        data : data,
        cache : false,
        async: false,

        timeout: app.AJAX_CALLS_TIMEOUT, // 15secs
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success : function(data) {

            callback( data );
            // Reseting call counter
            thisModel.callCounter = 0;
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            // try until limit reached 
            if ( thisModel.count != app.AJAX_CALLS_LIMIT ) {
                thisModel.addproduct( callback , viewObj );
            } else {
                callback( xhr );
            }
        }
    });
```

After 10 seconds ajax produces this error on *alert(xhr.statusText)* but the process completes on the backend ...This happens only on iOS chrome.. why I am getting this error .. please help .

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [jQuery: Error With POST After Being Offline (iOS & Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682973/jquery-error-with-post-after-being-offline-ios-chrome)

It appears to be a bug in iOS, and Apple keeps closing the bug I keep filing on it.